# Ubuntu 14.04 Go to Switch Account without goint through Lock Account

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

Okay. So the new Ubuntu 14.04 decided that user needs to lock their account first then, switch account. So my question is How can I go straight to Switch Account screen without going through the Lock screen. I feel this part is backward and really annoying, especially on a shared computer.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the idea might be that if you know which user-id you want to sign onto you would select it immediately from the menu rather than using "Lock/Switch Account".

With that covered the expectation might be if you select Lock/Switch Account you want to sign on later with another id but are ready to put aside and safeguard the privacy of your current work now.

Irregardless, you can choose the Lock/Switch Account option and then, without unlocking your account, select Switch Account from the corresponding menu from the Lock Screen.

You simply skip unlocking your old session.

Comment: Its a shared PC. So after I use, it might be a few minutes or a few hours before someone else use it. In the mean time, I would like to go to the switch account screen and leave it there.